# Sharepoint SP Services

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, spservices

I am using following code to get Sp List Items and display them

```
$().SPServices({

            operation: 'GetListItems',
            async: false,
            webURL: '/',
            listName: 'Sample',

            completefunc: function (xData, Status) {

                $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode('z:row').each(function () {
                    var groupname;
                    groupname = $(this).attr("ows_Group");
                    if (groupname == $(this).attr("ows_Group")) {
                        var ibcresultList = "<div class='shortcutsItem'><a href='" + $(this).attr("ows_URL") + "'>" + $(this).attr("ows_Header") + "</a></div>";
                        $("#asSamTab").append(ibcresultList);
                    }
                    else {
                        var ibcgroupchange = "<div class='shortcutsItem LobWhiteSpaceleft'></div><div class='shortcutsItem LobWhiteSpaceRight'></div>";
                        $("#asSamTab").append(ibcgroupchange);
                    }
                });
            }
```

my list items are follows

```
Title URL Group
row1  //   A
row2  //   A 
row3  //   A
row4  //   B
row5  //   B
row6  //   A
```

My ouptput should be as follows

```
row1   row2
row3   row6
----   ----
row4   row5
```

can anyone help how to achieve this

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to add this in before your completefunc to force ordering by Group then Title in the results returned, if not you need to do your own sorting after getting the results back:

```
CAMLQuery: "<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Group' /><FieldRef Name='Title' /></OrderBy></Query>",
```

Edit:
I have verified against other lists this will return the data in the correct output. Use the browser development tools to see that in fact the data is returned in the correct order.

However looking at your code, you'll never get the results you are looking for even with ordering the CAML query above.  In your completefunc, you are creating a new variable called groupname. You are setting the current item groupname to this variable. Then you are evaluating if this value equals itself, which will always return true. You are never going to hit your else function with this code.

Edit2:
I would do it like this, (untested):

```
$().SPServices({
    operation: 'GetListItems',
    async: false,
    webURL: '/',
    listName: 'Sample',
    CAMLQuery: "<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Group' /><FieldRef Name='Title' /></OrderBy></Query>",
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
        //create a variable to evaluate against
        var groupname = "";
        $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode('z:row').each(function () {
            //create a variable holding the current group
            var thisGroup = $(this).attr("ows_Group");
            if (groupname === thisGroup || groupname === "") {
                var ibcresultList = "<div class='shortcutsItem'><a href='" + $(this).attr("ows_URL") + "'>" + $(this).attr("ows_Header") + "</a></div>";
                $("#asSamTab").append(ibcresultList);
            }
            else {
                var ibcgroupchange = "<div class='shortcutsItem LobWhiteSpaceleft'></div><div class='shortcutsItem LobWhiteSpaceRight'></div>";
                $("#asSamTab").append(ibcgroupchange);
            }
            //finally update the groupname for the next pass through the function
            groupname = thisGroup;
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: its not working not sure between Title is working but group order is not working

Comment: What is not working with it? The results should be coming back ordered by group then title.

Comment: i am seeing title are in order but group is not in order  row1 to   row6 are in order irrespective of group

Comment: I've verified on several lists that this will return things in proper order, it looks like you also have bad logic with this:var groupname;
                    groupname = $(this).attr("ows_Group");
                    if (groupname == $(this).attr("ows_Group")) groupname is always going to equal groupname because you are setting the value to the current item Group value. This is likely the source of your problem.

Comment: can you try by removing title and order by group

Comment: Edited answer, your code is preventing you from getting the results you want.

Comment: i have issue with my group column, above caml query works, now i am trying to find logic to detect a logic to go to else if group changes, let me know if you have  thoughts o that

Comment: edited again with untested code

Comment: Its working but if it enters to else condition its thinking as reading one variable means total 8 items and if 4 times and else 2 times so its reading only 6 times

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to say there.

Comment: for example i have 3 items like row1 A, row2 A, row3 B for first two items it goes to if condition and third items it goes to else condition, i can see output only for first two items in place of third item i see else part  and it exits out of loop as it count only for 3

Comment: That's what it is supposed to do, if the query returns 3 items with 2 being the same group, then it is working as expected. At this point, you need to do some troubleshooting on your end or become more familiar with javascript. I can't develop your solution for you. I've given you quite a bit of information to go on here. As I understand your requirement, this gives the desired output.